Using a shortcode to get User Emails by role as specified in the shortcode, need help to allow for multiple roles
I have the following working code:
function get_emails_by_multiple_roles ( $atts ) {

$user_args = shortcode_atts ( array (
        'role' => 'role' ,
    ), $atts );

    $users = get_users( $user_args );

    foreach ( $users as $user ) :
        $role_emails[] = $user->user_email;
    endforeach;

    $all_role_emails = implode(', ', $role_emails);
    return $all_role_emails;
}
add_shortcode('multiple_roles_emails', 'get_emails_by_multiple_roles');

Ofcourse this works as following:
[multiple_roles_emails role="administrator"]

for example, but now i need help to get it to work as the following:
[multiple_roles_emails role="administrator, author"]

Any help would be appreciated.

If you're trying to get users with all roles (in your example, administrator and author), your code looks like it should work.
If you want users with any role (administrator or author, you'll need to split the string in the role attribute into an array using explode(), and use the role__in array.
Something like this should work:
function get_emails_by_multiple_roles ( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array('role' => '' ), $atts );
    $roles = explode( ',', $atts[ 'role' ] );
    // Trim whitespace from the role names.
    foreach ( $roles as $key => $role ) {
        $roles[ $key ] = trim( $role );
    }

    $user_args = array ( 'role__in' => $roles );

    $users = get_users( $user_args );

    foreach ( $users as $user ) :
        $role_emails[] = $user->user_email;
    endforeach;

    $all_role_emails = implode(', ', $role_emails);
    return $all_role_emails;
}
add_shortcode('multiple_roles_emails', 'get_emails_by_multiple_roles');

